# Keeps giving Undefined variable error in routing framework code

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, url-routing

I need to make a simple routing system.

I need to redirect when i type the url `localhost/user/login` it need to go to the UserController file, and also exactly the same with just when you type `localhost` it needs to go to the HomeController.

- Check whether the requested controller exists and if so, 'include' it.
- Check if the requested method exists, and if so, call it.
- Include only the controller that is important for that URL
- If the controller does not exist, print a 404 Not found message.
- If the method does not exist, print a 404 Not found message.
- Also return a 404 status code for 404 pages.

It keeps giving an error with undefining a variable, and when I `/` to a page it keeps giving an undefined variable error.

When change the `$_server` to `$_SERVER` it doesn't work at all. This is the error it gives when using `$_server`:

> Notice: Undefined variable: _server in C:\xampp\htdocs\src\index.php
> on line 2
>
> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\src\index.php on line 2
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\src\index.php on line 3

***Down here are the files I use.***

```
<?php
$linkExplode = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

if (empty($linkExplode[1] && empty($linkExplode[2]))) {
    $linkExplode[1] = 'Home';
    $linkExplode[2] = 'index';
}

$controller = empty($linkExplode[1]) ? 'home' : $linkExplode[1];
$method = empty($linkExplode[2]) ? 'index' : $linkExplode[2];

if (file_exists('./Controllers/' . ucfirst($controller) . 'Homecontroller.class.php')) {
    require('./Controllers/' . ucfirst($controller) . 'UserController.class.php');
    $classname = ucfirst($controller) . 'Controller';
    $class = new $classname();

    if (method_exists($class, $method)) {
        $class->$method();
    } else {
        http_response_code(404);
        die;
    }
} else {
    http_response_code(404);
    die;
}
```

***HomeController***

```
<?php
class HomeController
{
    public function index() 
    {
        echo 'De home pagina!';
    }
}
```

***UserController***

```
<?php
class UserController
{
    public function login() 
    {
        echo 'De login pagina!';
    }
}
```

***Htacces***

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ src/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
DirectoryIndex src/index.php
```

***Currently Var_Dumping $_SERVER Giving this back***

```
array(58) { ["REDIRECT_MIBDIRS"]=> string(24) "C:/xampp/php/extras/mibs" ["REDIRECT_MYSQL_HOME"]=> string(16) "\xampp\mysql\bin" ["REDIRECT_OPENSSL_CONF"]=> string(31) "C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf" ["REDIRECT_PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR"]=> string(10) "\xampp\php" ["REDIRECT_PHPRC"]=> string(10) "\xampp\php" ["REDIRECT_TMP"]=> string(10) "\xampp\tmp" ["REDIRECT_STATUS"]=> string(3) "200" ["MIBDIRS"]=> string(24) "C:/xampp/php/extras/mibs" ["MYSQL_HOME"]=> string(16) "\xampp\mysql\bin" ["OPENSSL_CONF"]=> string(31) "C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf" ["PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR"]=> string(10) "\xampp\php" ["PHPRC"]=> string(10) "\xampp\php" ["TMP"]=> string(10) "\xampp\tmp" ["HTTP_HOST"]=> string(9) "localhost" ["HTTP_CONNECTION"]=> string(10) "keep-alive" ["HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL"]=> string(9) "max-age=0" ["HTTP_SEC_CH_UA"]=> string(64) ""Google Chrome";v="95", "Chromium";v="95", ";Not A Brand";v="99"" ["HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_MOBILE"]=> string(2) "?0" ["HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_PLATFORM"]=> string(9) ""Windows"" ["HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS"]=> string(1) "1" ["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]=> string(114) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36" ["HTTP_ACCEPT"]=> string(135) "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9" ["HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE"]=> string(10) "cross-site" ["HTTP_SEC_FETCH_MODE"]=> string(8) "navigate" ["HTTP_SEC_FETCH_USER"]=> string(2) "?1" ["HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST"]=> string(8) "document" ["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]=> string(17) "gzip, deflate, br" ["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]=> string(35) "nl-NL,nl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7" ["HTTP_COOKIE"]=> string(36) "PHPSESSID=auct5lh5cga85hmln0o54kfjf4" ["PATH"]=> string(964) "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\jeann\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Users\jeann\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\jeann\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\PHP;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Users\jeann\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\jeann\Pictures\gradle-7.1.1\bin;C:\Users\jeann\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator;C:\Users\jeann\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools;C:\Users\jeann\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;C:\Users\jeann\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin" ["SystemRoot"]=> string(10) "C:\WINDOWS" ["COMSPEC"]=> string(27) "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe" ["PATHEXT"]=> string(53) ".COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC" ["WINDIR"]=> string(10) "C:\WINDOWS" ["SERVER_SIGNATURE"]=> string(95) "
Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.11 Server at localhost Port 80
" ["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]=> string(47) "Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.11" ["SERVER_NAME"]=> string(9) "localhost" ["SERVER_ADDR"]=> string(3) "::1" ["SERVER_PORT"]=> string(2) "80" ["REMOTE_ADDR"]=> string(3) "::1" ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=> string(15) "C:/xampp/htdocs" ["REQUEST_SCHEME"]=> string(4) "http" ["CONTEXT_PREFIX"]=> string(0) "" ["CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=> string(15) "C:/xampp/htdocs" ["SERVER_ADMIN"]=> string(20) "postmaster@localhost" ["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=> string(29) "C:/xampp/htdocs/src/index.php" ["REMOTE_PORT"]=> string(5) "51472" ["REDIRECT_URL"]=> string(11) "/user/login" ["REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING"]=> string(14) "url=user/login" ["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]=> string(7) "CGI/1.1" ["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]=> string(8) "HTTP/1.1" ["REQUEST_METHOD"]=> string(3) "GET" ["QUERY_STRING"]=> string(14) "url=user/login" ["REQUEST_URI"]=> string(11) "/user/login" ["SCRIPT_NAME"]=> string(14) "/src/index.php" ["PHP_SELF"]=> string(14) "/src/index.php" ["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]=> float(1636987064.7515) ["REQUEST_TIME"]=> int(1636987064) }
```

Comment: Well `$_SERVER` is definitely correct. PHP is case-sensitive about variable names. So what exactly happens when you try to use that?

Comment: @ADyson Well, it doesnt load the page at all. ```This page can not be found on the localhst``` (Thank you for editing the question correctly)

Comment: That sounds like a 404 - did you check the status code? So presumably it's not crashing, but is redirecting you to a page which actually exists. Did it change the URL?

Comment: @ADyson Correct it is a 404, but its not redirecting me like it should do, also not changing the link.

Comment: Ok so, 1) what was the original URL? 2) What URL did it redirect you to? 3) What URL did you expect to be redirected to, and why? Please give specific details of the problem - we can't fix vague descriptions. Thanks.

Comment: Your 4th line of php is also wrong. `if (empty($linkExplode[1] && empty($linkExplode[2]))) {` should be `if (empty($linkExplode[1]) && empty($linkExplode[2])) {` - Actually you have a few things wrong. That whole If statement checking $linkExplode[1] and $linkExplode[2] is useless since the 2 rows right below you are doing inline if to check the exact same thing. Also your `file_exists` function makes sure a file exists and then you include a different (controller) file

Comment: @ADyson Yeah ok, sorry! I need to redirect when i type the url ```localhost/user/login``` it need to go to the UserController file, and also exactly the same with just when you type ```localhost``` it needs to go to the HomeController.

Comment: Yeah True, @slashroot 

But how am i suposed then to redirect to the other page then?

Comment: `I need to redirect when i type the url localhost/user/login`... you mean it should redirect to index.php and then run the "login" function of the "usercontroller" class?

Comment: @ADyson No, it should redirect to the UserController.php file when typing the ```localhost/user/login```

Comment: @ADyson I dont think he actually means redirect, but more like include the correct controller class by url.

Comment: Surely `if (file_exists('./Controllers/' . ucfirst($controller) . 'Homecontroller.class.php')) {` should be `if (file_exists('./Controllers/' . ucfirst($controller) . 'Controller.class.php')) {` . Why did you hard-code `Home` into that? And the same, why did you hard-code `User` into the line below that? Is it left over from some testing and you forgot to take it out?

Comment: Yeah, exactly @slashroot

Comment: `it should redirect to the UserController.php file`...well you haven't written any code to do such a redirect. What you've written is code which will try to pick out "user" and "login" from the URL and then try to `require` the correct file, and call its functions - as I just described. "Redirecting" is when you tell the browser to change to a different URL. The only redirecting currently specified is in your htaccess file.

Comment: aha, okay. My Bad! @ADyson 

Hmm yeah but thats whats basicaly what need to happen, if ur typing the url ```localhost/user/login``` it need to include the file Usercontrol.php

Comment: Ok. And what is happening currently? Have you done any detailed, line-by-line debugging to see where the data / code flow deviates from your expectation? Try to narrow down the issue. slashroot and I have pointed out some potential logic flaws in the code already, so you should probably address those to begin with.

Comment: Yeah okay, i was just debugging the code line by line, and came a across ```Undefined index: REQUEST_URI in C:\xampp\htdocs\src\index.php on line 2
```

Comment: That's weird. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] should always exist, unless you're running the code from the command-line (which it doesn't sound like you are)

Comment: no point fixed it. But still giving this same error. ```This page can not be found on the localhost```

Comment: @Shawty that error is cause the 404 is being thrown.. Try and figure out where in the if the 404 is being thrown it will help you to narrow down at least where its happening.

Comment: @slashroot yeah, i removed the 404 errors now, to just see the error. but its now just giving a blank page so it looks like there is something wrong with finding the right file on the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, is make sure you HTACCESS route works. If it does and brings you to the correct page then on to the next step.

Second step understanding your PHP code here, there are a couple contradictions and fixes you need.

```
<?php
$linkExplode = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

//YOU CAN REMOVE THIS WHOLE IF STATEMENT
if (empty($linkExplode[1] && empty($linkExplode[2]))) {
    $linkExplode[1] = 'Home';
    $linkExplode[2] = 'index';
}

//You should check that the $linkExplode isset as well as not empty
$controller = isset($linkExplode[1]) && !empty($linkExplode[1]) ? $linkExplode[1] : "Home";
$method = isset($linkExplode[2]) && !empty($linkExplode[2]) ? $linkExplode[2] : "index";

// Here we remove the 'hardcoded HOME and USER from the string 'Controller.class.php' 
// AND you also need to make sure that you require the same file your verifying is actually there.
if (file_exists('./Controllers/' . ucfirst($controller) . 'Controller.class.php')) {
    require('./Controllers/' . ucfirst($controller) . 'Controller.class.php');
    $classname = ucfirst($controller) . 'Controller';
    $class = new $classname();

    if (method_exists($class, $method)) {
        $class->$method();
    } else {
        http_response_code(404);
        die;
    }
} else {
    http_response_code(404);
    die;
}
```

Comment: Its still not loading the page at all hmm, i think there is a problem with the isset

Comment: Are you getting any type of error?

Comment: Yeah there still  is @slashroot

Comment: Yeah no, when removing all the 404 errors, like i did no its just showing only a blank page.

Comment: @Shawty Alright well if its not working then there should be an error being thrown. If there are no errors being thrown, then you will need to find out at what point its breaking. You said you removed the 404 redirects but is the `die;` still there? Cause that will stop it all from running and wont display an error.

Comment: No there is no die just this is deleted all ```else {
        http_response_code(404);
        die;
    }
} else {
    http_response_code(404);
    die;
}
```

Comment: You should be verifying line-by-line since your having issues. I would suggest starting right under the `$controller` and `$method` vars. Echo those 2 vars and do a die(); right after. See that those values are what you expect them to be. If its all good, then continue by checking your code line-by-line until you figure out where its going wrong. As of right now, with a blank page being displayed and nothing happening it seems like its getting into one of your `else` statements, figure out which one and at that point you can get a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking what PHP version you are using. I had errors with almost a similar case while using 8.1 had to downgrade to native 7.4 and the error went away. This was my error `PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "SERVER_SIGNATURE"` could help.